# Fatal error with fetch_array(mysqli_both)

Tags: php, mysqli

I am receiving a "Fatal error" once the function fetch_array(mysqli_both) is invoked. The file below on the `while` instance is exactly where the error is coming from.

```
    <?php
include 'connect.php';
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT a.name,j.link,j.points, a.submit_time from journal j, article a where a.journal_id = j.id and a.professor_id = $id");
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Article</th>
        <th>Journal</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
<?php
while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row[0] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[1] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[2] ?></td>
        <td><?php $date = date_create($row[3]);
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?></td>
    <tr>
<?php   
}
?>
</table>
```

When i try it on my wampserver i don't have this problem as i activated couple of PHP extensions. Online, i don't think it's easy to activate such extensions. Do you think this error is related to the fact that i didn't invoked the `$query` as a variable with `$mysqli` in line 4?

Comment: What  $_SESSION['user_id'] contains? ... You should post the error info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use `require_once('connect.php');` because it is a needed file for this code.

Also you have to check your **$mysqli** variable if it's a correct connection to your database.

For more help you might have to post the full Error-Message

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /homepages/journaltable.php on line 16

Comment: then you might have an error in your SQL-Syntax. Try to run it on phpmyadmin.

Comment: I think it has to be _journal AS j_ and _article AS a_

Answer (score 0):

you should check result before fetch:

```
if ($res) {
while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
...
...
}
} else {
echo printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
```